# how to open download manager by clicking?

Tags: android

how do i make it open the default download manager app by clicking on a file being downloaded from the statusbar? i want to handle the downloads in the same webvew, not in any other browser. this method handles it but i am not able to click the downloading files-

```
// Download manager
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);

        }
    });
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

also it downloads files without it's original name . every file is called "download" i want to fix this

Comment: Maybe everything is called download because this line `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");`

Comment: no, i tried removing that already and every file is called "filedownload"

Comment: What I meant to say was I would suggest using the end part of the URI instead of the hard coded string of "download"

Comment: cant i request the download manager to download it directly? just like the stock browser

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722111/how-do-i-use-downloadlistener

Comment: it opens the 3rd party browsers. i have that code already